# Firestore setDoc - Response Undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

## Overview

I am creating a react-native application using Firestore as a database and authentication service. I am currently allowing users to create accounts using the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` which is successful. I am using the returned `UID` to create a document in my database with the same UID so I can store information about them later such as subscription, invoices, name, etc.

## Question

I am successful in creating the document but I don't get any response back from Firestore letting me know things worked out well. It says *Undefined* when I try to log the res.
**Are we suppose to retrieve the document to ensure it worked?** This seems like like a bad pattern, I would expect a status code or something back.

```
 const addUserToDatabase = (uid, email) => {
      setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
        uid: uid,
        email: email,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("response:", res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("unable to add user to database", err);
        });
    };
```

As an add on on question, I am doing two calls in one user command, creating and account and then adding the document. There is a scenario where as user could be created but no document created. This would be a bad situation. How can I make sure that if the document is not created then the account should not be created; vice versa? Both must succeed

```
 createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password)
      .then((credentials) => {
        console.log(credentials);
        if (credentials.user?.uid) {
          const { uid, email } = credentials.user;
          addUserToDatabase(uid, email);
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        switch (err.code) {
          case "auth/email-already-in-use":
            setAuthError("That email is already in use");
            break;
          default:
            console.log("did not create account:", err);
            setAuthError("uncaught error");
            break;
        }
      });

    const addUserToDatabase = (uid, email) => {
      setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
        uid: uid,
        email: email,
      })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("response:", res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("unable to add user to database", err);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at this code:

```
setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
  uid: uid,
  email: email,
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log("response:", res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("unable to add user to database", err);
});
```

The behavior is as follows:

- If the call to `setDoc` itself completes, the write operation was committed to the local cache and will be synchronized with the server if/when a connection is available.
- The call to `setDoc` itself raises an exception, the local write operation failed and was aborted (this is rare).
- The the promise resolves (and thus your `then` block executes), the data was written on the server.
- If the promise is rejected (and thus your `catch` block executes), the data was rejected on the server - typically because of your security rules, but check the error that you get to be certain of the cause.

So depending on what you want to detect, you can either declare success in the `then` block (for a completed write on the server) or on the first line after the code I shared here (for a completed local write).

Comment: I am used to use rest apis where I expect a status code. from your explanation it appears we assume it worked if don't get into the catch block. Is this correct?

Comment: It's exactly what I said above: if the `then()` callback is called, the data has been committed on the server. So if that's what you mean by "it worked", then yes the `then` block would be the place to handle that.