# Dart/Flutter + Firestore: How to get added object id in an offline setting?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form to create a new contact which also includes a "create"-button. When clicking on this button I want the form to go into readonly-mode, and after the creation was successful I would like to redirect to the page related to the new contact.

Going into readonly works fine, but I'm having issues with the redirect in an offline setting. The following code for createButton works in an online setting, where createButton is within a stateful widget containing the state "pending":

```
setState(() {
  pending = true;
});
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(...).withConverter(...).add(contact).then((addedContact) {
  setState(() {
    pending = false;
  });
  context.goNamed('contact', params: {'contactId' : addedContact.id});
});
```

In an offline setting however, the listeners regarding the related collection all get updated with the new contact, but this callback never resolves.

I currently think about manually generating an id, listening in on the collection and redirect when an object with that id is created, but are there any best practices for such cases?

Maybe relevant: I'm testing it as a Web-App and do the following calls on initialization:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.enablePersistence(const PersistenceSettings(synchronizeTabs: true));
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.disableNetwork();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is the expected behavior. The `then` listener only gets called once the document has been written on the server, which won't happen when you're offline.

The full behavior is as follows:

- If the call to `add` itself completes, the write operation was committed to the local cache and will be synchronized with the server if/when a connection is available.
- If the call to `add` itself raises an exception, the local write operation failed and was aborted (this is rare).
- If the `then` block gets called, the data was written on the server.
- If the `Future` is rejected (and the `catch` block executes), the data was rejected on the server - typically because of your security rules, but check the error that you get to be certain of the cause.

Also see my answer here: [Firestore setDoc - Response Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944671/firestore-setdoc-response-undefined/75944708#75944708)

---

So your current code only calls `setState` once the data has been written on the server. If you want to instead have it run after the data was written to the local cache, you should not use a `then` block but have the code straight after the `add` call:

```
setState(() {
  pending = true;
});
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(...).withConverter(...).add(contact);
setState(() {
  pending = false;
});
context.goNamed('contact', params: {'contactId' : addedContact.id});
```

This means the state will be pending pretty briefly though, as the local write will complete very quickly. I often aim for a UI that is similar to WhatsApp to display the status, for example by showing a single checkmark when the data was written locally, and a double checkmark when it has also been committed to the server.

---

Finally, to get the ID of the document in an offline setting, have a look at this code from the third code sample in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#dart_8):

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
final data = <String, dynamic>{};

final newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();

// Later...
newCityRef.set(data);
```

Your call to `add(...)` is split into two here:

- `doc()`, which generates the new unique ID and is a pure client-side operation that works offline too.
- `set(...)`, which actually write the data.

So in the above code, you can get the new ID from `newCityRef.id`.